# image display on jsp page

Tags: java, html, jsp, jsp-tags, jspinclude

i am using`<img src="../img/image.gif" />` to display the image on jsp but it show a smalll icon.
img folder are parallel to jsps folder
Directory structure:
    WebContent
              jsps
                   .jsp files
              foo
                  img
                      images.gif
             WEB-INF

Comment: dude, isnt this a dupe of your last 3 questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042759/jsp-does-not-display-whole-animation

Comment: Stop reposting the same question over and over. Click `edit` link below your question to add more information to it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable in your jsp that points to the context of your application

```
<c:set var="ctx" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
```

and use it to reference your images

```
<img src="${ctx}/images/theme/middle_banner.jpg" />
```